# TFS non-chronological deployment?

Tags: deployment, team-foundation-server, branching

We have the following scenario:

Changeset #1 is some unfinished buildable checkin
Changeset #2 is a completed small task
..
Changset #5 completes the work done at CS#1

They all affect the same output dll.

How do we deploy changes done at CS#2 without the other work? Also how can we avoid this situation happening again in the future?

Answer (score 1):

We (using SVN) usually solve this by using feature branches. This enables larger features to be only merged to the mainline after they are finished. A great article about different strategies is here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151207060910/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/02/12/vsts-ranger-projects-branching-guidance-ii.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in that case you should try to "disable" your #1 changeset.

let's say if it is a new feature, don't make any way to make this code run in the application.

if it is a replacement of an existing code, write it while the old code is in use, and enable it when it is done

Answer (score 0):

Use a feature branch or a [shelveset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx). Both will allow you to store the work in progress on the server and run a Team Build. A feature branch is a bit more heavyweight but can also be more flexible.